# How to change Eclipse extraced method template?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

The code standard at my work, is to put the "{" on their own line instead of after the arguments of a method. We're using lots of method extraction as we are in a refactoring heavy state.

Unfortunately, auto-extracted methods place the "{" on the wrong line and since no dev notices it every time, our standard isn't so standard anymore. Is there a way to change it? Thanks

I want this

```
void foo () {
//stuff
}
```

to be this

```
void foo () 
{
//stuff
}
```

Comment: You can use [Google code style](https://github.com/google/styleguide) in Eclipse

Comment: Considered using “format on save” always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Code Style` > `Formatter`, `edit` your active profile.

`Method declaration` in the `Braces` tab allows you to define this behaviour.